# Show more levels of exception in Python traceback

Tags: python, exception, python-3.x

I'm catching exceptions in context managers, however I don't see all levels of reraised exceptions. Anyone knows how to improve this?

```
import traceback

def f():
    try:
        raise Exception("Interesting")
    except Exception as e:
        raise Exception("Exc {} raised".format(e))

class Try():
    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        print("Exception {} raised".format(exc_val))
        print("".join(traceback.format_tb(exc_tb, 100)))
        return True

with Try():
    f()
```

Here I'd like to also see the code line of the "Interesting" exception (line 5) in the traceback, however I get

```
Exception Exc Interesting raised raised
File "try_test.py", line 19, in <module>
    f()
File "try_test.py", line 7, in f
    raise Exception("Exc {} raised".format(e))
```

Comment: Why not use `raise` in the exception handler to reraise the same exception? Do you have to wrap it in a new exception? In that case, you should probably also keep the traceback of the original exception.

Comment: Usually I'd like to introduce new context dependent information. For example reraising tells me what operation in particular failed (e.g. "Reading SQL data").

Comment: OK. And looking at your syntax, I assume we're talking about Python 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `traceback.format_exception` instead of `traceback.format_tb`.

See the [`traceback`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/traceback.html) documentation.